# XP Batch scripting - zipping with rinrar looping through a directory *.csv

Tags: scripting, windows-xp

I have read numerous articles now and it's not clear and there's lots of versions and this that and the other and I have been piecing things together and have got so far, my problem is the 'rar' command doesn't seem to accept my substition variable and instead reads it as a string.

But this is what I have

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL

set path=%path%;"C:\TEMP\Output" 
set _sourcedir=C:\TEMP\Output
set _logfile=c:\temp\Output\zip_log.txt
set _rarpath=C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR

echo Starting rar batch > %_logfile% 

:: Set default directory
pushd %_sourcedir% 
echo Scan Directory is %_sourcedir%
FOR %%f IN (*.txt) DO (
    echo %%f
    %_rarpath\rar.exe a test
)

popd

ENDLOCAL

@echo on
```

I have cut some out and chopped it so you only get the essence, I haven't omitted any commands though.

I am trying to loop through the directory and locate all `.txt` files and zip them into a `.rar` file.

The echo writes out the correct filenames.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is your problem:

```
set _rarpath=C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR
```

In batch files, the environment variable delimiter is a space, so it thinks `_rarpath` is `C:\Program`

Enclose the path in double quotes and see if that helps:

```
set _rarpath="C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR"
```

Also, in your FOR loop change

```
%_rarpath\rar.exe a test
```

to

```
%_rarpath%\rar.exe a test
```

(or,perhaps this was a typo?)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you're asking winrar to do anything with your files? %%f needs to be on the winrar command line somewhere.

Also, you shouldn't need a loop at all for this: rar.exe a test.rar %yourpath%*.csv or similar.

Comment: I'm currently not asking winrar to do anything yet,  all im doing is echoing the filenames for now.